# What is causing this "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'" error?

Tags: python, typeerror, raspberry-pi3

I know this may be a petty issue but I seriously couldn't find a solution to this problem. I am using this code:

```
# Import the modules
from __future__ import division
import spidev, datetime, time
from sys import exit
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

# Setup SPI
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0, 0)
spi.mode = 3

# Constants
accres = 16
accrate = 15

# Set GPIO chip select pins
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
cs1 = 23
cs2 = 24
motor = 18
GPIO.setup(cs1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(cs2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(motor, GPIO.OUT)

# Note: the duty cycle goes from 0.0 to 100.0, with 100.0 being no motor movement,
# and 0.0 being the maximum motor speed.
motor_output = GPIO.PWM(motor, 60)

# Initialize the ADXL345
def initadxl345():
    # Set data rate (accrate=15 -> 3200 Hz, 14=1600 Hz, 13=800 Hz, 12=400 Hz, 11=200 Hz, 10=100 Hz etc.)
    spi.xfer2([44, accrate])

    # Enable full range (10 bits resolution) and +/- 16g 4 LSB
    spi.xfer2([49, accres])

# Read the first ADXL x-y-z axes
def readadxl345_1():
    # Chip select pin ensures that the first sensor is being read by grounding its pin
    GPIO.output(cs1, 0)
    GPIO.output(cs2 ,1)

    rx = spi.xfer2([242, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
    out = [rx[1] | (rx[2] << 8), rx[3] | (rx[4] << 8), rx[5] | (rx[6] << 8)]
    # Format x-axis
    if (out[0] & (1 << 16 - 1 )):
        out[0] = out[0] - (1 << 16)
    # Format y-axis
    if (out[1] & (1 << 16 - 1 )):
        out[1] = out[1] - (1<<16)
    # Format z-axis
    if (out[2] & (1 << 16 - 1 )):
        out[2] = out[2] - (1 << 16)
    # Return human readable values
    return out

# Read the second ADXL x-y-z axes
def readadxl345_2():
    # Chip select pin ensures that the first sensor is being read by grounding its pin
    GPIO.output(cs1, 1)
    GPIO.output(cs2 ,0)

    rx = spi.xfer2([242, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
    out = [rx[1] | (rx[2] << 8), rx[3] | (rx[4] << 8), rx[5] | (rx[6] << 8)]
    # Format x-axis
    if (out[0] & (1 << 16 - 1 )):
        out[0] = out[0] - (1 << 16)
    # Format y-axis
    if (out[1] & (1 << 16 - 1 )):
        out[1] = out[1] - (1<<16)
    # Format z-axis
    if (out[2] & (1 << 16 - 1 )):
        out[2] = out[2] - (1 << 16)
    # Return human readable values
    return out

print("Vibration Reader Initializing...")
time.sleep(1)
print(GPIO.RPI_INFO)

response = input("Proceed measurements? [Y, n]")
pwm_speed = float(input("Motor PWM value: "))

if response == "Y" or "y":
    # Initialize the ADXL345 accelerometer
    print("Initializing ADXL345s...")
    initadxl345()
    motor_output.start(pwm_speed)

    timeout = 0.0003125 / 2 # timeout=1/samplerate=>not sufficient measurements. Half the time is sufficient (don't know why!)

    timetosend = 1

    while(1):
       with open('/proc/uptime', 'r') as f: # get uptime
           uptime_start = float(f.readline().split()[0])
       uptime_last = uptime_start
       active_file_first = "10bit" + str(accres) + 'g' + '.csv'
       file = open('/var/log/sensor/' + active_file_first, 'wb')
       while uptime_last < uptime_start + timetosend:

           time1 = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%S.%f'))
           sensor1 = readadxl345_1()
           sensor2 = readadxl345_2()
           file.write(str(sensor1[0]) + ',' + str(sensor1[1]) + ',' + str(sensor1[2]) + ',' + str(sensor2[0]) + ',' + str(sensor2[1]) + ',' + str(sensor2[2]) + ',' + time1 + '\n')

           # Print data every "timeout" second
           elapsed = time.clock()
           current = 0
           while(current < timeout):
               current = time.clock() - elapsed

    motor_output.stop
    print("Motor shutting off and cleaning up GPIO.")
    GPIO.cleanup()

elif response == "N" or "n":
    print("Quitting...")
    time.sleep(1)
    quit()
```

and the interpreter gives an issue with line 106, saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "accelerometer.py", line 106, in <module>
    file.write(str(sensor1[0]) + ',' + str(sensor1[1]) + ',' + str(sensor1[2]) + ',' + str(sensor2[0]) + ',' + str(sensor2[1]) + ',' + str(sensor2[2]) + ',' + time1 + '\n')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this or improve/streamline the code? I am using Python 3.8.1 and I am doing it on a Linux machine.

Comment: You are opening your file with `'wb'` which means write/binary. Do you need to write a binary file? maybe just change that to `file = open('/var/log/sensor/' + active_file_first, 'w')`?

Comment: Yes this fixed the problem. Also, how would I specify the `while(1):` loop to stop after  one second?

Comment: note: in python, it is idiomatic to use `while True: ...` instead of `while(1)`

Comment: I don't mean do be disrespectful, but I don't know how that applies to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have opened the file in "wb" mode for writing.

`file = open('/var/log/sensor/' + active_file_first, 'wb')`

So it is expecting the data to be written in the file to be `byte` objects.

You need to convert the string you are writing into `byte` object or maybe change the mode in which you opened the file to `"w"` mode.

`file = open('/var/log/sensor/' + active_file_first, 'w')`